# how insert data from fusion tables into MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, google-fusion-tables

i search many time without any solutions try to insert data from fusion table to MySQL by using PHP.
simply need to insert data from fusion tables into MySQL Db

below sample i used to insert the data to MySQL db

appreciate if you can help

the test table :15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","my_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

$sql="INSERT INTO my_table (address)
select name from fusion_tables";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{ die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }

echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

want to insert one column from fusion table to MySQl DB

[Fusion table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1hk1P7Dpm3nk1Z_QVxxzwboQWk56w350Fxpregew)

as a snapshot below link 
[Fusion table](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FTPVlpFISxs/UsCUd2TzZrI/AAAAAAAAAVw/MME8plXbmH4/w525-h452-no/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: you should probably explain what fusion tables is/are...  It's definitely not the thing you added in the tags.

Comment: thanks dear for support i add fusion table criteria and snapshot for one column in fusion table need to insert into MySQL DB using PHP.

Comment: I corrected the tags, hopefully now your question will attract the correct audience.